How to execute a powershell script via Task Scheduler?
i have saved a script at path : C:\Test\RealScript.ps1
with the following content
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Create the prompt
$messageBoxText = "Do you want to restart the PC?"
$caption = "Restart Confirmation"
$buttonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
$iconType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning

# Show the message box
$result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($messageBoxText, $caption, $buttonType, $iconType)

# Check the user's response
if ($result -eq [System.Windows.MessageBoxResult]::Yes) {
    # Force restart the PC
    Restart-Computer -Force
}

And i want to execute this script every "x" mins, right now i am gonna choose 1 minute ,
# Define variables
$scriptPath = "C:\Test\RealScript.ps1"
$taskName = "RunScriptEveryMinute"
$taskDescription = "This task runs the specified script every minute."

# Create the action for the task
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-NoProfile -File `"$scriptPath`""

# Create the trigger for the task to run every 1 minute with a reasonable repetition duration
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days 365)

# Create task settings to run the task whether the user is logged on or not
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable -MultipleInstances Parallel

# Register the scheduled task
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName $taskName -Description $taskDescription -Settings $settings -User "SYSTEM"

The respective task was formed in Task Scheduler but the script wasnt executed and nothing was prompted onto my device

Please take a look in your Windows eventvwr.msc (Event Viewer), or taskschd.msc (Task scheduler).

when i checked initially nothing was shown specifically i haven't checked event viewer yet will do that , is there any changes needed in the script ?

"is there any changes needed in the script" when the script is doing what you want it to do, then no changes are needed, but .....

there is no particular information from event viewer or task scheduler

The script seems to (try to) interact with the user. You should not run that as SYSTEM, but as a normal user. (or As Administrator)

You may need to add -ExecutionPolicy Bypass in the action's argument:
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File `"$scriptPath`""


that doesnt work

I just tested with your code with registering the scheduled task but replace the action with just writing the timestamp to a file.
Without the -ExecutionPolicy Bypass, the action will fail with a return code of 2147942401, and after adding the -ExecutionPolicy Bypass, the action completed successfully the next minute and I got the timestamp in the file.
However, as others had pointed out, you are running the task as SYSTEM and the MessageBox will not show up in your current user session.  The scheduled task will be stuck at the MessageBox prompt, shown as Running.

could you give me your code that you used to test it out
